# Help with recursive function

Tags: recursion, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

I need some help understanting how the following conclusion was made:

We have the recursive function: $ε_n=-n \cdot ε_{n-1}$

How do we come to the conclusion that $ε_n=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n!\cdot ε_1$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1=n(n-1)!,$ so 
$$\epsilon _n=(-1)\epsilon_{n-1}=(-n)(-(n-1))\epsilon _{n-2}=(-1)^2n(n-1)\epsilon _{n-2}=\underbrace{\cdots}_{\text{Do it $n-1$ times}}=(-1)^{n-1}n(n-1)\cdots 2\cdot \epsilon _1.$$

Answer (score 0):

You could prove it by mathematical induction.

Base case:  $n=1$:   $ε_1=(-1)^{1-1} \cdot ε_1=  ε_1$.

Inductive step:  if $ε_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-2}\cdot (n-1)!\cdot ε_1$, then $ε_n=-nε_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n!\cdot ε_1$.